# ANSI *absolute* cursor position in terminal when scroll overflows

Tags: c#, linux, ansi-escape

Is there a way to move the cursor in the terminal to the **absolute** position (that is, counting from the start of the command and not the window, in cases where the buffer has scrolled)?

So far, I am unable to do so

```cs
// Print n lines
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i ++)
{
    Conosle.WriteLine("Line {0}", i);
}
// Write text in line 3
Console.Write(
    "\x1b[3;0H"
    + "This line was replaced"
);
```

The output should look something like this:

```
Line 1 
Line 2
This line was replaced
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
```

Instead it looks like this:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
...
Line 45
Line 45
This line was replaced
Line 45
Line 45
```

Comment: There is no such absolute position - the terminal is independent of the commands run from the shell. I don't believe there are any escape codes for dealing with the buffer - the buffer may not exist.

Comment: @NetMage so there is no way to, say, scroll to the top (ie, the first line where the command was invoked)?